# Rebar include ext libs error

Tags: erlang, rebar

rebar config:

```
{deps, [
  {ibrowse, ".*",
   {git, "git://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse.git", "master"}}
]}.
```

When make:

```
Uncaught error in rebar_core: {'EXIT',
                              {badarg,
                                  [{re,run,[git,[],[{capture,none}]]},
                                   {rebar_deps,is_app_available,3},
                                   {rebar_deps,find_deps,3},
                                   {rebar_deps,preprocess,2},
                                   {rebar_core,acc_modules,5},
                                   {rebar_core,process_dir,4},
                                   {rebar_core,process_commands,1},
                                   {rebar,main,1}]}}
```

make: *** [all] Error 1

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config file worked for me so I'd suggest doing the following:

1. make sure you have git installed
2. put the most recent build of [rebar](https://github.com/downloads/basho/rebar/rebar) in your project directory
3. use a Makefile like the one I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085704/erlang-and-toolchains/)
4. delete your existing deps directory
5. run `make`

If you want to use rebar directly instead of using make you can do:

```
$ ./rebar get-deps
$ ./rebar compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error yesterday, and it was because I was using an older version of rebar, or perhaps because I was using a version of rebar compiled on a different system. Try recompiling rebar with the latest versions of both erlang and rebar.