# Is there a convention for placing rebar in the search path?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm attempting to understand how to build a multiple-application Erlang OTP release using Rebar.

My applications include Webmachine, Riak, and a few applications of my own devising. So far, I have been running Rebar successfully in the application root directory. But the Rebar bootstrap program suggests that there may be a better way. E.g.:

"You now have a self-contained script called "rebar" in
your current working directory. Place this script anywhere in your path
and you can use rebar to build OTP-compliant apps."

I can think of several ways to do this. But I'm wondering:

Is there is a preferred convention: e.g., placing Rebar in an .erlang file, /usr/local/bin, etc., etc.?

Many thanks,

LRP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I keep a copy in `/usr/local/bin`, which I use when creating new apps. For example:

```
$ rebar create-app appid=myapp
```

All of my projects are built with rebar by placing the binary in the root directory of my project and referencing it locally in my Makefile as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085704/erlang-and-toolchains/5137948#5137948). As of this writing, this seems to be the convention the community has adopted. For example, [nitrogen](https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen), [mochiweb](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb), [ibrowse](https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse), and [erlydtl](https://github.com/evanmiller/erlydtl) are all built this way.

Personally, I'm not a big fan of including the rebar binary with every project but I don't see a good alternative. It makes life easier for people that either don't have rebar in their path, or don't have an updated version in their path.

I suspect this is a temporary situation. Eventually the rebar project will start to have fewer commits, and we'll all agree to keep a copy in our path. At that point we can all stop including it. Of course, if your projects are only going to be used by you, this is a non-issue.